# How to add a docker image in the Dockerfile for making a docker container

Tags: shell, docker, makefile, dockerfile

I am fairly new to docker containers and images. I am trying to make a Dockerfile with ubuntu 18.04 and another docker image from http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_download.html#docker tool. 
Later, I want to generate a docker container for the above-linked tool as a base image and ubuntu as the parent image makefile. For example, here is how you will do it via command line for the installation of the image for the tool within ubuntu os.

`docker pull ensemblorg/ensembl-vep
docker run -t -i ensemblorg/ensembl-vep ./vep`

When I try to install the `Ubuntu:18.04` and the above docker image via make file it says

```
docker build -t "KM:vep-96.0" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
18.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
5bed26d33875: Pull complete 
f11b29a9c730: Pull complete 
930bda195c84: Pull complete 
78bf9a5ad49e: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bec5a2727be7fff3d308193cfde3491f8fba1a2ba392b7546b43a051853a341d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:18.04
 ---> 4e5021d210f6
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER ARJ
 ---> Running in 8f1f7e837703
Removing intermediate container 8f1f7e837703
 ---> 511205d197d6
Step 3/4 : RUN pull ensemblorg/ensembl-vep
 ---> Running in b584b3b1738c
/bin/sh: 1: pull: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c pull ensemblorg/ensembl-vep' returned a non-zero code: 127
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'docker-build' failed
make: *** [docker-build] Error 127
```

Here is how my `Dockerfile` looks like,

```
# NGS580 container for making reports with R 3.4.3
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER ARJ

# ~~~~~ VEP ~~~~~ #
FROM pull ensemblorg/ensembl-vep
run -t -i ensemblorg/ensembl-vep ./vep
```

I would like to know whether or not it is possible to have another docker image within a `Dockerfile`? If not how can I have the tool without needing to install a lot of modules? Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: [ensemblorg/ensembl-vep](https://hub.docker.com/r/ensemblorg/ensembl-vep) already uses `ubuntu:18.04` as a base image, so you can start with `FROM ensemblorg/ensembl-vep`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, So I have tried with `FROM ensemblorg/ensembl-vep` and later when I wanna add other file using,
`RUN -i -v $HOME/vep_data:/opt/vep/.vep \
ensemblorg/ensembl-vep \
perl INSTALL.pl \
- ---> Running in ed1a0c286cd5
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option - 
The command '/bin/sh -c -i -v $HOME/vep_data:/opt/vep/.vep ensemblorg/ensembl-vep perl INSTALL.pl -a cf -s homo_sapiens -y GRCh38' returned a non-zero code: 2
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'docker-build' failed
make: *** [docker-build] Error 2a cf -s homo_sapiens -y GRCh38` It is agagin throwing error,
``

Comment: Is this still in your dockerfile?  It should not be: # ~~~~~ VEP ~~~~~ #
FROM pull ensemblorg/ensembl-vep
run -t -i ensemblorg/ensembl-vep ./vep

Comment: @user1017373 you're mixing Dockerfile instruction with Docker container commands. You can't do `RUN -i -v ...`. Check [Dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder) for available instructions and how to use them and [`docker container run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) commands or explore CLI with `--help` (`docker container run --help`).

Comment: I can run it as `docker run` without issues in the command line.  However, I need all these tother in the docker file. And so, my question is, whether or not is it possible?
For example, from `FROM  ensemblorg/ensembl-vep  ` and  also 
`docker run -t -i -v $HOME/vep_data:/opt/vep/.vep ensemblorg/ensembl-vep perl INSTALL.pl -a cf -s homo_sapiens -y GRCh38` all togther in the `Dockerfile`